# Animation as Gatsby's website "used by" section?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, gatsby

Can anyone help with an animation used by gatsby in their official website < https://www.gatsbyjs.com/ > in the used by logo slider section, I've tried to inspect the element and I found this ->

[image: Gatsby official website]

Also, I've tried to search on their open source git repo < https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/www > and its huge, no success.

Seems not to be too complicated to do it manually though, Does anyone has any ideia how can I implement that animation-1qdclt7 keyframe?

Thank you!

Comment: Scroll down to the very bottom of styles list and you will see `keyframes` for this animation. `0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); -ms-transform: translateX(0); transform: translateX(0); } 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); -ms-transform: ranslateX(-100%); transform: translateX(-100%); }`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `<ul>` tag:

```
.css-zpz5mt {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-animation: animation-1qdclt7 60s linear infinite;
    animation: animation-1qdclt7 60s linear infinite;
}
```

Detailed animation (`animation-1qdclt7`):

```
@keyframes animation-1qdclt7{
  0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0); 
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```